# Mysql Syntax error - Backtics won't solve it

Tags: mysql, syntax

I'm compiling a query in PHP to insert products in the db:

```
$query = "";

if ($A > 0) {$query .="INSERT INTO ped_prod (`ped_id`, `prod_id`, `cant`) VALUES ($last_id, 1, $A); ";}

if ($B > 0) {$query .="INSERT INTO ped_prod (`ped_id`, `prod_id`, `cant`) VALUES ($last_id, 2, $B); ";}

if ($C > 0) {$query .="INSERT INTO ped_prod (`ped_id`, `prod_id`, `cant`) VALUES ($last_id, 3, $C); ";}
```

While running the query through `mysql_query($prodquery, $conexion)` I'm getting the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
'INSERT INTO ped_prod (`ped_id`, `prod_id`, `cant`) VALUES (13, 3, 2)' at line 1
```

I have tried:
- Exchanging quotes ('), double quotes (") and backticks (`)
- Checking the list of MySQL reserved words
- Running the query in PHPmyAdmin (it says '#1 affected line' but it loads the data to the table, which is not the case when executing the script in the browser)

What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can cram them into an array. i offen load 1000 rows in 1 stmt do u want to see that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_query()` supports just one query at a time. See the [respective PHP docs](http://php.net/mysql_query):

> mysql_query() sends a unique query (*multiple queries are not supported*) to the currently active database on the server that's associated with the specified link_identifier.

So in your case, just run each `INSERT` statement seperatly and you should be fine.

Another option, as all your inserts are similar, would be to connect those by concatenation of the value clauses:

```
$values = array();
if ($A > 0) {$values[] ="($last_id, 1, $A)";}

if ($B > 0) {$values[] ="($last_id, 2, $B)";}

if ($C > 0) {$values[] ="($last_id, 3, $C)";}

// echo query if needed
if ( count( $values ) > 0 ) {
  $queries = 'INSERT INTO ped_prod (`ped_id`, `prod_id`, `cant`) VALUES ' . implode( ',', $values );

  // execute query
  //  ...
}
```

<sup>Besides, `mysql_X` functions are deprecated. Switch to [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli).</sup>

Comment: Thanks! That's a great idea to solve it! Still, you must remove the semicolon in order to work so it looks like *** $values[] ="($last_id, 1, $A) ";

Comment: @KUMO Corrected. Too much copy/paste.